# React app deployment to github pages failed

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment

I followed the instructions at [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment).

but when I run this command `npm run deploy` this error comes out

[image: error when running run deploy]

Comment: Please add error info in the post (as text), its hard to find from screenshot.

Comment: error info?  you mean debug_log?

Comment: For e.g. copy paste entire npm run deploy command output and add in your question.

Comment: this is output of command only error